# Running multiple Equinox OSGi frameworks

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

I'm trying to run multiple Equinox instances within a plain Java application.

Currently, I am starting one instance of Equinox in my application using:

```
EclipseStarter.startup(new String[]{"-console", "-dev", "bin"}, null);
```

However, for a new use case, which requires a lot of bundle starting, stopping and updating, this approach is no longer sufficient.

Instead, I would like to be able to hold two frameworks with different installed bundles at the same time and swap between them if neccessary.
In some cases, I would still need to stop and re-start some bundles, but such an approach would deal with most of the pain.

Any idea how I could setup such an approach???

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Sebastian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use EclipseStarter. Use the OSGi [launching API](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/launch/package-summary.html) to create multiple instances of the framework.

Comment: This sounds resonable, thank you. Still, I am facing problems with this approach. Starting the second framework after starting and using the first framework is no problem anymore. However when I request a service from the second framework, I cannot cast it into the correct service. It seems the class loaders are not matching although the same cast worked a second before with a service I got from the first framework. To both framework system packages I export the package of service. Do you have any idea, why this is a problem? Is it possible to export the same package to multiple frameworks?

Comment: I found a solution for my problem. It seems Equinox itself has problems with multiple frameworks. I create new frameworks with ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next(). Using Felix from Apache is working with this approach. Equinox on the other hand seems to have problems with this. No idea why...

Comment: Equinox creates a new class loader to host each child framework. I think this is to resolve some statics in the framework impl.

Comment: Yes, the same does Felix. The problem wasn't Equinox by the way. It works fine now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple static instances by using a different ClassLoader for every one of them. Create multiple [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) with the path set to the JarFile containing the EclipseStarter class. Use the loadClass() method of the ClassLoader to obtain a reference to the EclipseStarter class object.